# Oracle PL/SQL No data found - non consecutive Id values

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a report with the following structure:

Column 1 ID, Column 2 Approved_Rejected_Status, Column 3 Rep_Id

I'm getting a no data found error while running the following:

```
DECLARE 

V_REP_ID VARCHAR2(100);
V_ROWS_APPROVED_min NUMBER;
V_ROWS_APPROVED_max NUMBER;
V_STAT VARCHAR2(100);


BEGIN
    SELECT min(id) INTO V_ROWS_APPROVED_min FROM MY_TABLE; 
    SELECT max(id) INTO V_ROWS_APPROVED_max FROM MY_TABLE; 
    
    FOR i IN V_ROWS_APPROVED_min..V_ROWS_APPROVED_max LOOP
    
        SELECT APPROVED_REJECTED_STATUS INTO V_STAT    
        FROM MY_TABLE  WHERE MY_TABLE.ID =i;
        
        SELECT REP_ID         INTO V_REP_ID 
        FROM MY_TABLE  
        WHERE MY_TABLE.ID = i;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I think it has something to do with the ID having non consecutive values perhaps?
(I can't have consecutive values on the report for functionality, neither include an exception cause I need to to perform actions depending on the type_of_change)

Thank you

Edit:
Thank you MT0 for your review/suggestion!
I tried using a cursor for loop and something really weird is happening:

```
for cur_m in (select id, approved_rejected_status 
            from bdc_bench_watchlist_t
            order by id) 
loop

    if cur_m.approved_rejected_status = 'Approved' then 
        --Inserting into a test table:
        insert into index_test (ID_COPY, MY_APPROVED_STATUS)
        values (cur_m.id,   cur_m.approved_rejected_status);
    end if;
end loop;
```

The result brings all the range of IDs (from the min to the max) ok but! the approved_rejected_status column is empty (only the header is showing with null data on the rows). I have no idea why.
If I do a basic select id, approved_rejected_status from the source table it brings everything ok (id and status info ok).

Thank you

Comment: *"the approved_rejected_status column is empty (only the header is showing with null data on the rows)"* Do you mean the insert into `INDEX_TEST` is populating only  `ID_COPY`, and leaving `MY_APPROVED_STATUS` null? Some sample data would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need to iterate through every number and do something even if there is no row there then just handle the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception:

```sql
DECLARE 
  V_REP_ID            MY_TABLE.REP_ID%TYPE;
  V_ROWS_APPROVED_min MY_TABLE.ID%TYPE;
  V_ROWS_APPROVED_max MY_TABLE.ID%TYPE;
  V_STAT              MY_TABLE.APPROVED_REJECTED_STATUS%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT min(id), max(id)
  INTO   V_ROWS_APPROVED_min, V_ROWS_APPROVED_max
  FROM   MY_TABLE; 
    
  FOR i IN V_ROWS_APPROVED_min..V_ROWS_APPROVED_max LOOP
    BEGIN
      SELECT APPROVED_REJECTED_STATUS, REP_ID
      INTO   V_STAT, V_REP_ID   
      FROM MY_TABLE 
      WHERE MY_TABLE.ID =i;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        V_STAT := NULL;  -- Or put default values here.
        V_REP_ID := NULL;
    END;
    -- Do stuff with the stat/rep_id
  END LOOP;
END;
```

If you don't want to iterate through every row and want to skip the missing id values then you could use a cursor and order by id.

Comment: Thank you! 
Tried the cursor but got the results added to the question.
Do you know what might be happening? Thanks!

Comment: Found a workaround (not the best but it's working at least):
Create a cursor for each case needed with where statements.
Thanks!